# using python telethon to receive mp3 files and save them locally

Tags: python, telethon

I have a python script that sends message to a channel and that channel replies back by sending the voice of that message.
So what I want to do is, use telethon to send the message (that I have done with "`client.send_message(id, message)`") but how I can get the mp3 file that I'm receiving in the reply and save it locally

please note that it takes 4+ seconds to get the reply depending on the message size

[image: example of message reply]